# How do I change the src of an image when I scroll into a certain div using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I've been working on a personal portfolio or sorts and I've been having a lot of fun, but I'm stuck at a certain problem.

Basically, the top of the website is covered by an image that is fairly dark, so on mobile devices I've put a white menu icon in the top right corner. The problem is that the portion of the site below the dark picture has a white background, so naturally you can't see the menu icon.

Basically, when I scroll into the white portion of the page, I want to change the src of the menu icon from nav-icon to nav-icon-black using jQuery. How would I go about doing so? Can I make it turn back to white whenever I scroll back up into the darker region of the site?

Comment: the web is full of tutorials and plugins for this...let google be your friend

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of jQuery should do it.

You didn't provide example code or JSFiddle (which is bad thing !), but I am a good guy with no job at 1 o'clock after midnight so I did it for you.

**[Click here for JSFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/384w1xzq/)**

This is just some basic example that changes the color of a fixed box div (in your case will be the menu box) when the top level goes beyond 200px (the header height) on scroll. Otherwise 
it the box will change to white.

**Javascript code:**

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
        $('#menu-bar').css('background', '#000');
    } else {
        $('#menu-bar').css('background', '#fff');
    }
});
```

Anyway in your case if you want to change the src of the element (I guess it's a `<img>`), you just need to do get the element with selector and change the src using `attr()`.

```
$('#menu-bar').attr('src', '/path/to/img/nav-icon-black.png');
```

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks! I thought about adding my code, but I decided not to just because I was looking for a general example. Guess next time I should post it anyway. I'll try implementing this and get back to you.